# Como generar un random sin repeticion en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

En el código hay un `arrayPreguntas` donde guardo el numero de preguntas que ya están establecidas a través de un `crud`, pero necesito que cuando aparezca la 
pregunta no se vuelva a repetir.

```
 public void seleccionarPreguntaAleatoria() {

    Random r = new Random();

    int n;

     n = r.nextInt(arrayPreguntas.size());

    X = (PreguntaClass) arrayPreguntas.get(n);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar los indices de los elementos que contienes en el Array `arrayPreguntas`, obtener un valor aleatorio de estos indices y vas eliminando el indice que aparezca para evitar que se repitan.

Crea lista de indices:

```
   int max = prjcts.size();
    final List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>(max);
    for(int c = 0; c < max; ++c) {
        indices.add(c);
    }
```

Obtiene valor aleatorio

```
int arrIndex = (int)((double)indices.size() * Math.random());
if(indices.size()>0) {
  //Indice aleatorio
  int randomIndex = indices.get(arrIndex);
  System.out.println("Valor: " + indices.get(randomIndex);
  //Remueve indice aleatorio para evitar repetición.
  indices.remove(arrIndex);
}
```